# Typescript - type to represent any class?

Tags: reflection, typescript, types

What type should I use in typescript to represent any class?

I'm trying to write a function that takes an array of classes and returns an array with different order.

```
function shuffle(classes: typeof Object[]) : typeof Object[] {
    return ...;
}

class A { }
class B extends A { }
class C extends B { }
class D extends B { }
shuffle([A, B, C, D]);
```

> Argument of type 'typeof A[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObjectConstructor[]'.

Then I've tried:

```
shuffle([typeof A, typeof B, typeof C, typeof D]);
```

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObjectConstructor[]'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ObjectConstructor'.

What's the right way? Generics? How? This doesn't work:

```
export function <T extends typeof Object> shuffle(classes: T[]) : T[]
```

This neither:

```
export function <T extends Object> sortClassesBySpeciality(classes: typeof T[]) : typeof T[]
```

<strike>Also why `typeof (typeof A)` is `"string"` and `"" + typeof A` is `function`?</strike> Ok, got this, `typeof` has two very different meanings context of type definition and expression.

*(The ultimate goal is to sort the classes by level of `extends` from `Object`.)*

Comment: Here's the result - [sortClassesBySpeciality(classes: Array<AnyClass>) : Array<AnyClass>](https://gist.github.com/OndraZizka/2aaa89e0db90c7e4b99a414e06706756)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should avoid using the type `Object` in typescript, you better use `any` as [the docs say](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any):

> You might expect Object to play a similar role, as it does in other
>   languages. But variables of type Object only allow you to assign any
>   value to them - you can’t call arbitrary methods on them, even ones
>   that actually exist

But if you want to represent classes then you need to have the following form:

```
{ new (): CLASS_TYPE }
```

Or in your case:

```
function shuffle(classes: Array<{ new (): any }>): Array<{ new (): any }> {
    return [];
}

class A { }
class B extends A { }
class C extends B { }
class D extends B { }
shuffle([A, B, C, D]);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20shuffle(classes%3A%20Array%3C%7B%20new%20()%3A%20any%20%7D%3E)%3A%20Array%3C%7B%20new%20()%3A%20any%20%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20B%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20D%20extends%20B%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Ashuffle(%5BA%2C%20B%2C%20C%2C%20D%5D)%3B))

If all of your classes are based on a super class (as your example implies) then you can simply do:

```
function shuffle(classes: Array<{ new (): A }>): Array<{ new (): A }> {
    return [];
}
```

---

#### Edit

Just saw that you want to

> sort the classes by level of extends from Object

To answer that:

```
function shuffle(classes: Array<{ new (): any }>): Array<{ new (): any }> {
    return classes.sort((a, b) => getInheritanceLevel(a) - getInheritanceLevel(b));
}

function getInheritanceLevel(cls: { new (): any }): number {
    let level = 0;

    while (Object.getPrototypeOf(cls.prototype) !== Object.prototype) {
        level++;
        cls = Object.getPrototypeOf(cls.prototype).constructor;
    }

    return level;
}

shuffle([D, A, C, B]); // returns [A, B, D, C]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20shuffle(classes%3A%20Array%3C%7B%20new%20()%3A%20any%20%7D%3E)%3A%20Array%3C%7B%20new%20()%3A%20any%20%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20classes.sort((a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20getInheritanceLevel(a)%20-%20getInheritanceLevel(b))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getInheritanceLevel(cls%3A%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20any%20%7D)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20level%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20while%20(Object.getPrototypeOf(cls.prototype)%20!%3D%3D%20Object.prototype)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20level%2B%2B%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cls%20%3D%20Object.getPrototypeOf(cls.prototype).constructor%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20level%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20B%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20D%20extends%20B%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Ashuffle(%5BD%2C%20A%2C%20C%2C%20B%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20returns%20%5BA%2C%20B%2C%20D%2C%20C%5D))

Comment: Am I right that the type syntax means "type(s) whose constructor returns `A`"? So there's no direct support like `Class<T extends A>` like in Java? How would this work with interfaces?

Comment: It's more like a "type who has a constructor for A", you can also define static class functions there. I don't think that there are plans to make it more like the java way, but what are you missing from the typescript way? It suits what you're after.

Comment: Also, it could also be `{ new (): any }[]`, is that equivalent?

Comment: I've introduced an alias: `type AnyClass = { new (): any };`

Comment: Yeah, should be fine. The convention is to call those constructors, so `type AnyConstructor`, just like the [ArrayConstructor](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L1259)